# Official cases are not shared (multiprocessing.sharedctypes)

Tags: python, multiprocessing

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Lock
from multiprocessing.sharedctypes import Value, Array
from ctypes import Structure, c_double

class Point(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('x', c_double), ('y', c_double)]

def modify(n, x, s, A):
    n.value **= 2
    x.value **= 2
    s.value = s.value.upper()
    for a in A:
        a.x **= 2
        a.y **= 2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lock = Lock()

    n = Value('i', 7)
    x = Value(c_double, 1.0/3.0, lock=False)
    s = Array('c', b'hello world', lock=lock)
    A = Array(Point, [(1.875,-6.25), (-5.75,2.0), (2.375,9.5)], lock=lock)

    p = Process(target=modify, args=(n, x, s, A))
    p.start()
    p.join()

    print(n.value)
    print(x.value)
    print(s.value)
    print([(a.x, a.y) for a in A])
# 7
# 0.3333333333333333
# b'hello world'
# [(1.875, -6.25), (-5.75, 2.0), (2.375, 9.5)]
```

From the official tutorial, it's wrong. It's strange. Why isn't it shared. Official case: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html

Expected results:

```
# 49
# 0.1111111111111111
# HELLO WORLD
# [(3.515625, 39.0625), (33.0625, 4.0), (5.640625, 90.25)]
```

Comment: I get precisely the expected results when I run it.  What are you getting?

Comment: I got the initial value.

Comment: Which version of yours Python

Comment: Works for me in 3.7, 3.8, 3.9, and 3.10.

Comment: I get the expected results with Python 3.9 and Python 2.7 on Linux, and Python 3.8 on Windows.

Comment: What python version are you using, what OS, and how are you running the script (IDE or terminal)?

Comment: I also use anconda( python3.8 ) and win10.

Comment: I'll try to reinstall it.

Comment: Try running the script from a cmd prompt like so: `>python myscript.py` to make sure it's not any IDE getting in the way. Multiprocessing is not something that should go wrong unless you modified the library in some way

Comment: Your suggestion is effective. Thank you very much!!!